# Computing directional derivatives of the max of three different functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider $f_1,f_2,f_3: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$f_1(x):= (1/2)|x|, f_2(x):= (x-1)^2, f_3(x):=(1/2)[(1/2)x+1]$

and take $g(x):=\text{max}\{f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x)\}$

How do I compute the directional derivatives

$g'(x_0,1), g'(x_0,-1), g'(x_1,1)$ and $g'(x_1,-1)$

if I know that $g$ is not differentiable at $x_0=1/4$ and $x_1=2$?

In particular, I am not sure what $g(x)$ is actually conveying, since isn't  the max of all those individual functions undefined?

Is g simply the max value out of all the functions at some given point?

In any case how would I compute say the first and third of those directional derivatives?

edit: in case my notation is unfamiliar let
$g'(x_0,v) := \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{g(x_0+tv)-g(x_0)}{t}$

For $g'(x_0,1)$ is there anything further than 
$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{g(x_0+t) - g(x_0)}{t}$ which I can do?

Comment: There is no such thing as a directional derivative for functions of one variable. Your g'(x_0,1)$, etc., don't make sense.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  I've recognised my lecturer does not use standard notation, but I have defined it in my edit, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing $g'(x_0,-1)$ as an example.

After drawing the graphs and finding the maximums, we see that 
$f_2(x)$ is the max outside $[0.25,2]$ and $f_3(x)$ is the max from $[0.25,2]$

$g'(x_0,-1) := \lim_{t \to 0^-} \frac{g(0.25-t)-g(0.25)}{t}$

Since we are taking left hand limit at $x_0 = 0.25$, $g(x) = (x-1)^2$

then
$$\lim_{t \to 0^-} \frac{(0.25-1-t)^2-(-0.75)}{t}$$
$$\lim_{t \to 0^-} \frac{0.75^2-1.5t+t^2+0.75)}{t}$$
$$\lim_{t \to 0^-} \frac{-1.5t+t^2}{t}$$
$$ = -1.5$$